# Julia : JLD package doesn't work when running Julia development version

Tags: julia

The current version of Julia is 0.4.6.  I, however, am running the development version 0.5. Suddenly JLD doesn't work.  It's installed and updated. Yesterday I compiled code using JLD but this morning it doesn't work.

```
julia> using JLD
INFO: Precompiling module JLD...
WARNING: Method definition convert(Type{#T<:AbstractString}, AbstractArray{#S<:Union{Char, Int32, UInt32}, 1}) in module Base at unicode/utf32.jl:131 overwritten in module LegacyStrings at /root/.julia/v0.5/LegacyStrings/src/utf32.jl:133.
WARNING: Method definition isvalid(Array{Char, 1}) in module Base at unicode/utf32.jl:177 overwritten in module LegacyStrings at /root/.julia/v0.5/LegacyStrings/src/utf32.jl:179.
WARNING: New definition 
    string(Union{Char, LegacyStrings.UTF8String, LegacyStrings.ASCIIString}...) at /root/.julia/v0.5/LegacyStrings/src/utf8.jl:161
is ambiguous with: 
    string(Union{Char, UTF8String, ASCIIString}...) at unicode/utf8.jl:166.
To fix, define 
    string(Char...)
before the new definition.
WARNING: both LegacyStrings and Base export "UTF16String"; uses of it in module JLD must be qualified
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: UTF16String not defined
 in include(::ASCIIString) at ./boot.jl:234
 in include_from_node1(::ASCIIString) at ./loading.jl:417
 in include(::ASCIIString) at ./boot.jl:234
 in include_from_node1(::ASCIIString) at ./loading.jl:417
 [inlined code] from ./boot.jl:237
 in anonymous at ./<no file>:4294967295
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:237
 [inlined code] from ./sysimg.jl:11
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
 in _start() at ./client.jl:318
while loading /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/jld_types.jl, in expression starting on line 11
while loading /root/.julia/v0.5/JLD/src/JLD.jl, in expression starting on line 130
ERROR: Failed to precompile JLD to /root/.julia/lib/v0.5/JLD.ji
 in error(::ASCIIString) at ./error.jl:21
 in compilecache(::ASCIIString) at ./loading.jl:496
 in compilecache(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:485
 in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:355
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:237
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the development version of Julia, you need to use the development versions of the packages (which works for packages where the developer keeps master up-to-date but hasn't tagged yet). If you run `Pkg.checkout("JLD")` to checkout master, JLD should work (works on my machine. Note you may need to `Pkg.update()` before checking out, and you may need to quit Julia and re-open it to recompile the new version).

But as a word of caution, don't use the development versions of Julia as a way to test things out. Remember, the language is still in alpha and there is no guarantee that the package ecosystem or Julia itself will work with the daily master. The dailies are good for working on the language and preparing packages for the next version (and being ballsy I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using Julia 0.5 which is still in development.  If you switch to 0.4.6 then it should be fine.  I'm using that and JLD works fine for me.  You could also trying running `Pkg.update()` closing Julia, then reopening, to see if that helps.